# How to report my user answers in this experiment?

Tags: confidence-interval

I have conducted an experiment where users view a set of 3D images and after observing each image, they answer a forced choice question with 8 options (they select a number from 1 to 8). They also indicate their level of confidence about the answer on a continuous scale of 0 to 9. So for each image the user has viewed, this is what I have: - Their answer (an integer from 1 to 8) - a floating point number between 0 to 9 indicating how confident they are about their answer.

The true answer for each image is also an integer from 1 to 8.

Question: - I want to compare user answers with the true answers. How should the users' level of confidence be intervened in their answer?

Suppose I want to give a percentage of users' correct answers, can I do it with this method of data collection? Or should I report my results based on user confidence levels?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a calibration plot as one way of exploring this data. Bin the user's answers by level of confidence, and then look at the accuracy within each bin. A well-calibrated person, for example, should get roughly 50% of the items correct that they label as 40-60% confident, and roughly 90% of the items correct that they label as 80-100% confident. This doesn't directly assess how often the user is right, but rather assesses whether they can tell if they are right or not. If you're looking at accuracy, all you can do is look at their actual answer - especially with more than two options, even labeling an incorrect answer as low confidence doesn't mean they would get it right on the second, third, or fourth try.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense. How about pie charts?